# Verify session in php

Tags: php, sql, session, authentication

i have a login system to backoffice, but user verification don't work.

My code to login is:

```
$userName = isset($_POST["user-name"]) ? $_POST["user-name"]: '';
$userPass = isset($_POST["user-pass"]) ? $_POST["user-pass"]: '';

if ($userName != '0' && $userPass != '0'){

    $criptSen = hash("whirlpool", $userPass);
    $rediURL  = isset($_GET["url"]) ? $_GET["url"]: ''; 

    $SQL = "SELECT Usuario, Senha, Rank FROM utilizadores WHERE Usuario='$userName' AND Senha='$criptSen' limit 1";
    $query = mysql_query($SQL);

    if (mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $_SESSION['Usuario'] = $row['Usuario'];     
        $_SESSION['Rank']    = $row['Rank'];
        mysql_free_result($query);

        if($row['Rank'] == 0){
            header("Location: membro.php");
        } else {
            if($row['Rank'] == 1) {
                header("Location: admin/index1.php");                
            }
        }       

    } else {
        if (isset($query)){
            mysql_free_result($query);
        }
        header('location: index.php');      
    }   

} else {
    header('location: index.php');
}
?>
```

My code to verify session is true is:
When i login he doens't work fine, i think this code is wrong and i need your help to build it correctly.

```
<?php
@$Usuario = $_SESSION["Usuario"];
@$Rank   = $_SESSION['Rank']

if(!(isset($Usuario) && isset($Senha))){

$url = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

header("Location: index1.php?url=$url[3]");

} else if(isset($Usuario) && isset($Senha)){

$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT Usuario, Senha FROM utilizadores WHERE Usuario='$Usuario' AND Senha='$Senha' AND Rank=1");

if(mysql_num_rows($SQL) == 0){
    echo "<script>alert(\"Area Restrita\");</scrpit>";
    header("Location: ../index.php");
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you call `session_start()`?

Comment: What does happen when you try to log in?  A couple of points I notice directly: 1 - you set both `$userName` and `$userPass` to emtpy strings if not submitted in post data but then compare to the string `'0'` in `if ($userName != '0' && $userPass != '0'){` so you try to log in the user even if nothing is submitted. 2 - you are way open to SQL injections attacks if you build your `$SQL` query string like that

Comment: Put `session_start()` in the code of the bottom ?

Comment: session_start() has to come before you use anything involving sessions, so usually you put it at the top if the page uses session variables, etc.